# Shell script (bash) to match a string variable with multiple values

Tags: string, bash

I am trying write a script to compare one string variable to a list of values, i.e. if the variable matches (exact)  to one of the values, then some action needs to be done.

The script is trying to match Unix pathnames, i.e. if the user enters / , /usr, /var etc, then to give an error, so that we do not get accidental corruption using the script. The list of values may change in future due to the application requirements. So I cannot have huge "if" statement to check this.

What I intend to do is that in case if the user enters, any of the forbidden path to give an error but sub-paths which are not forbidden should be allowed, i.e. /var should be rejected but /var/opt/app should be accepted.

I cannot use regex as partial match will not work

I am not sure of using a where loop and an if statement, is there any alternative?

thanks

Comment: Use the case statement. `case $input in /|/usr/var|/etc|...) printf >&2 'Invalid input! %s\n' "$input"; exit 1;; esac`

Comment: Or use a regex with anchoring: `if [[ "$input" =~ ^(/|/usr/var)$ ]]; then...`

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use associative arrays for this.

```
declare -A nonoList=(
   [/foo/bar]=1
   ["/some/other/path with spaces"]=1
   [/and/so/on]=1
   # as many as you need
)
```

This can be kept in a file and sourced, if you want to separate it out.

Then in your script, just do a lookup.

```
if [[ -n "${nonoList[$yourString]}" ]] # -n checks for nonzero length
```

This also prevents you from creating a big file ad `grep`'ing over it redundantly, though that also works.

As an alternative, if you **KNOW** there will *not* be embedded newlines in any of those filenames (it's a valid character, but messy for programming) then you can do this:

```
$: cat foo
/foo/bar
/some/other/path with spaces
/and/so/on
```

Just a normal file with one file-path per line. Now,

```
chkSet=$'\n'"$(<foo)"$'\n' # single var, newlines before & after each
```

Then in your processing, assuming `f=/foo/bar` or whatever file you're checking,

```
if [[ "$chkSet" =~ $'\n'"$f"$'\n' ]] # check for a hit
```

This won't give you accidental hits on `/some/other/path` when the actual filename is `/some/other/path with spaces` because the pattern explicitly checks for a newline character before and after the filename. That's why we explicitly assure they exist at the front and end of the file. We assume they are in between, so make sure your file doesn't have any spaces (or any other characters, like quotes) that aren't part of the filenames.

If you **KNOW** there will also be no embedded whitespace in your filenames, it's a lot easier.

```
mapfile -t nopes < foo
if [[ " ${nopes[*]} " =~ " $yourString " ]]; then echo found; else echo no; fi
```

Note that `" ${nopes[*]} "` embeds spaces (technically it uses the first character of `$IFS`, but that's a space by default) into a single flattened string. Again, literal spaces before and behind key and list prevent start/end mismatches.

Comment: I get this error..
 nonoList: /: must use subscript when assigning associative array

Not sure about Associative Array, but for each element should have key and value pair, so shouldn't I give a key for each value?

Comment: Apologies - was working on another alternative and got them crosswired. My bad - correcting.

Answer (score 0):

Paul,

Your alternative work around worked like a charm. I don't have any directories which need embedded space in them. So as long as my script can recognize that there are certain directories to avoid, it does its job.

Thanks